# How to get service bus message lock token in Python?

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

I am using Service Bus to send messages to a topic with three subscriptions. Once a new message comes in, an Azure function is triggered by it (`'azure.functions.servicebus.ServiceBusMessage'`). I want to delete this message from its respective subscription once the Azure Function has finished.

I've been reading and I've seen that to do so, I'd need to specify both the `message_id` and the `lock_token`. I have managed to obtained the `message_id` but I have no clue where I can find the `lock_token`.

The type of message I am receiving in my Azure Function is `<class 'azure.functions.servicebus.ServiceBusMessage'>` if I print the `dir()` I get the following:

```
 ['_ServiceBusMessage__body', '_ServiceBusMessage__content_type', '_ServiceBusMessage__correlation_id', '_ServiceBusMessage__delivery_count', '_ServiceBusMessage__expiration_time', '_ServiceBusMessage__label', '_ServiceBusMessage__message_id', '_ServiceBusMessage__partition_key', '_ServiceBusMessage__reply_to', '_ServiceBusMessage__reply_to_session_id', '_ServiceBusMessage__scheduled_enqueue_time', '_ServiceBusMessage__session_id', '_ServiceBusMessage__time_to_live', '_ServiceBusMessage__to', '_ServiceBusMessage__user_properties', '__abstractmethods__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_abc_cache', '_abc_negative_cache', '_abc_negative_cache_version', '_abc_registry', 'content_type', 'correlation_id', 'delivery_count', 'expiration_time', 'get_body', 'label', 'message_id', 'partition_key', 'reply_to', 'reply_to_session_id', 'scheduled_enqueue_time', 'session_id', 'time_to_live', 'to', 'user_properties']
```

So I can get the message id by `message.message_id` but I couldn't find the way to get the `lock_token` which I need to do the following and delete my message:

```
from azure.servicebus.control_client import ServiceBusService, Message    
sb_client.delete_subscription_message(topic, subscription, message_id, lock_token)
```

The message I am using to trigger my Azure Function is imported from `azure.servicebus.control_client`

I have already tried `message.complete()` and `message.delete()` but these methods are not implemented in `azure.functions.servicebus.ServiceBusMessage`.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any code that you could share?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written so far.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai updated!

Comment: @GauravMantri updated!

Comment: Why not `message.complete()`?

Comment: @AnoopRDesai as you can see in ``dir()`` it is not implemented this method...

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, you really don’t have to explicitly delete the message. Once the function completes successfully without any exception, the message will be automatically deleted by Function runtime.

Comment: That's not working... I also thought so but my queue is growing and messages are not being deleted

Comment: I'm surprised. Based on the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior, the message should delete automatically.

Comment: Have you set ```"sessionHandlerOptions": { "autoComplete": true}``` in your function host.json. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using v7.0.0 https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/7.0.0/

The `ServiceBusMessage` has a property `lock_token`